# Codeigniter & PHPMailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, phpmailer

So I've been trying this for a day or two now. At first, I tried the built in codeigniter SMTP mail class, with no luck. In hope of fixing this problem, I turned to PHPMailer. And to my disappointment, there is still no luck.

I'm certain that all details are correct. I've even tried multiple SMTP servers, those of which include gmail and mandrill.

Here's the code that I am using (I have tried many different modified versions of this, but I'll give you the one that I'm currently using)

```
<?php

class thankyou extends CI_Controller {

function index()
{

    $this->load->model('index');

    $header = array(
        'title' => 'Please Confirm',
        'navigation' => $this->index->loadNavigation(),
    );

    $this->load->view('header', $header);

    $this->load->library('My_PHPMailer');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';                 // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // Set the SMTP port
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'email@outlook.com';                // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password4mandrill';                  // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

    $mail->From = 'hello@whatever.co.uk';
    $mail->FromName = 'Whatever';
    $mail->AddAddress('hello@whatever.co.uk', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient              // Name is optional

    $mail->IsHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <strong>in bold!</strong>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

}

}

?>
```

If need be, you can [Test it here](http://producerdesign.co.uk/thankyou)

I just get the error `2014-06-09 11:18:40   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`

Comment: please remove your smtp username and password

Comment: ok so the error is that it cannot connect to the smtp server. Maybe the smtp auth is false or try playing with the config files.

Comment: I know that they're not connecting. Like I said, I've tried many different codes and different smtp servers, I know for sure that the details I entered are correct

Comment: If this is the code you are using then why does the link at the bottom of your question attempt to connect to gmail at port 465? That would be the SSL not TLS port! From what you have posted the time-out is most likely an incorrect port setting -> but can't see if you have made minor mistake as the code you posted looks fine on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The actual port was changed before the code was posted, all the information was. Although, I have tried Gmail aswell, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'email@outlook.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password4mandrill';
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('you@outlook.com');
$this->email->to('dest@mail.com');
$this->email->subject('Test');
$this->email->message('Message');

if($this->email->send()) {
    echo 'Sent';
} else {
    $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

Full list of options: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 0):

Since Codeigniter have email helper you need not to use alternative way of complexity. You just load the helper and send mail using the following structure.

```
     $name="some name";
     $message="your text message";
     // set email data
     $this->load->library('email');
     $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
     $this->email->from($this->input->post('sender_email'), $name);
     $this->email->to('destination_email');
     $this->email->cc('alternative_email');
     $this->email->subject('Enquiry');
     $this->email->message($message);
     $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply. As mentioned in my earlier statement, I have already tried using the CodeIgniter default mail class, however there has been no luck with that either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is at a lower level than your script. SMTP connection failure means it's failing to even start talking to the server, so it has nothing to do with authentication or how you construct your message - all of them are gong to either call mail() or talk SMTP directly at some point and hit the same problem, as you're seeing.

The most likely explanation is that your DNS isn't working. Next I'd look at firewall issues, then make sure that `fsockopen` and `stream_socket_client` functions are not disabled in your php env.